# Specifying file name for saving html2canvas to local

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

So, I've managed to save the file programmatically using html2canvas and it manages to save the file. However, I would like to specify the name of the image that is rendered instead of it saving as "download". Is that possible? The current way I've implemented this is as follows:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
        window.location.href=image;
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats not working on the way you have it now?

Comment: At the moment, it saves it as a file with the name of "download". I would like to be able to specify the name of the file and the extension. (even without the extension, it does manage to open as an image so that's great)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
        var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = image;
         a.download = 'somefilename.png';
         a.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Connor Anderson Please check this solution, this will help you to specify the name of the file and the extension.

Comment: Would even be better to use `canvas.toBlob()` + FileSaver.js

Comment: Thanks for this Dixit! That solved the issue perfectly! :D